# Node.js - spawned process is generating error "execvp(): No such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, spawn, execvp

I have the following code that's intended to spawn and detach a child process, which is just another node.js script in the same directory. Here's the exact code I'm running:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var child = require('child_process');

var out = fs.openSync('/tmp/daemon.log', 'a');
var options = {
    cwd: process.cwd(),
    env: process.env,
    detached: true,
    stdio: ['ignore', out, process.stderr]
};

child.spawn('/usr/local/bin/node ./daemon.js', [], options).unref();
```

All `daemon.js` does right now is exit after a timeout of two seconds:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('done');
}, 2000);
```

If I run `daemon.js` directly from the terminal it works as expected. If I run the same command being passed to `child.spawn()` it works as expected. However when I run the script it generates this error:

```
execvp(): No such file or directory
```

It doesn't seem node.js specific and I'm having trouble working out what the problem is. Does anybody have any suggestions?

For reference, this is on OS X 10.8.5 Server with node installed using Homebrew at path `/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.25/bin/node` and symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/node`.

**EDIT**

The code now works perfectly, with the added avdantage of it not mattering which working-directory the main script is run from!

```
var fs = require('fs');
var child = require('child_process');

var out = fs.openSync('/tmp/daemon.log', 'a');
var options = {
    cwd: process.cwd(),
    env: process.env,
    detached: true,
    stdio: ['ignore', out, process.stderr]
};

child.spawn('/usr/local/bin/node', [__dirname + '/daemon.js'], options).unref();
```

Comment: I've tried defining the filename of the script as:
`var filename = process.cwd() + '/daemon.js';`
And logged out to ensure it's correct, but still the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing

```
child.spawn('/usr/local/bin/node ./daemon.js', [], options).unref();
```

To:

```
child.spawn('/usr/local/bin/node', ['./daemon.js'], options).unref();
```

Or:

```
child.spawn('node', ['daemon.js'], options).unref();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead try

```
__dirname+'/daemon.js'
```

Comment: The answer from user2837037 fixed the issue, but this helped me spawn the child process no matter where the parent script had been run from. Cheers!