# node.js python child-process won't print in realtime

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, inter-process-communicat

I'm trying to make a python program's stdout trigger an event for my node.js app to detect it and send that stdout's data to a client's browser.

The problem is the program won't deliver it's stdout until it terminates... and closes the pipe i guess.

I need it to be so as a line prints node gets the stdout after each print statement.

here's an example python program run with `python program.py`

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import os
import sys

for num in range(0,8):
    print('my []-- ', num)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Node which spawns a child process with

```
proc = spawn('python3 program.py -u')
var pid = proc.pid
echoIO( pid )
toggleState()
processDriver(proc)
```

below listens for the stdout and sends it to a browser with socket io

```
    function processDriver(proc) {
        proc.stdout.setEncoding('utf-8');
        proc.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            echoIO(data)                    
        })
        proc.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            var res = data.toString()
            echoIO(res)
        })

        proc.on('exit', function (code) {
            console.log(code)
            stateOff()
            echoIO("exit " + code)
            sendProcState(JSON.parse('{"status":"not_running"}'))
        })
    }
```

Also i've tested this problem in raspbian, ubuntu, and crunchbang, and the issue persists, no other solutions i've found on stackoverflow have worked yet. Sorry if this is about the 20th post.

EDIT: 
I've also run into this now

```
stderr - execvp(): No such file or directory
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
...
```

Comment: What child process program are you running?  Is it a standard program, one you can modify the source for, or something else?

Comment: its just any python program, I run it with 'python3 program_name.py'

Comment: Are you able to modify the Python program?

Comment: yes I can change the program to anything I need to get it to work

Comment: I'm starting to think its more of a system issue, after some playing around i manage to start to get errors in node, 
stderr - execvp(): No such file or directory


events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT

Comment: have you tried to put `-u` first: `python3 -u program.py`?

Comment: It wound up being a combination of things, but yes -u is part of the problem.

Comment: about `ENOENT`: you should probably run it as `spawn("python3", ['-u', 'program.py'])`

Comment: you should make that an answer :P J.F.

Answer (score 0):

> proc = spawn('python', ['program.py'], '-u')

it turns out my method of spawning the child was the error. It's a miracle that it ever spawned a child at all, playing with the code generated the error above, that led me to the post below.

But once I spawned it with this line, instead of a string with `'python program.py -u'` it worked.

[Node.js - spawned process is generating error "execvp(): No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992657/node-js-spawned-process-is-generating-error-execvp-no-such-file-or-directo)